# JEE7 @Transactional annotation not always fires

Tags: java, jpa, jta, java-ee-7, wildfly

For several days I'm trying to manage with JPA transactions after moving to WildFly 8 server and JEE7 and I cannot understand why in some cases @Transactional (javax.transaction.Transactional) annotation doesn't intercept method annotated with it. I cannot see any rule why sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Example of my not working code:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

import com.i4u.app.domain.AppDomain;
import com.i4u.app.mail.ComMailForm;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import com.i4u.qla.action.company.CmpFunctions;
import com.i4u.qla.model.invoice.Invoice;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class InvMailForm extends ComMailForm<Invoice> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private AppDomain           ad;

    @Inject
    private CmpFunctions        cf;

    @Inject
    private InvEmailFunctions   invEmail;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager       entityManager;

    @Override
    public void sendMail(String type) {
        if (type.equals("invoice")) {
            sendInvoice();
            inst = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method sends invoice and marks it as printed
     */
    private void sendInvoice() {
        try {
            invEmail.sendQlaInvoicePDFFile(inst, getSubject(), getContent(), getSendTo(), getBccTo());
            // sent invoice should be marked as printed
            printed();
            msg.message(msg.get("msg.Successful"), msg.get("msg.InvoiceWillBeSent"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            msg.fatalMessage(msg.get("msg.Failed"), msg.get("msg.FailedToSendInvoice"));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setSendTo(null);
        setBccTo(null);
    }

    public void sendPrepare(Invoice inv) {
        super.sendPrepare(inv);
        setSendTo(cf.getInvoiceEmail(inst.getCompany()));
        setSubject(inst.getCompanyName() + " - "
                + ad.getCompany().getName() + " week " + inst.getCweek());  
    }

    /**
     * Method sets invoice as printed
     */
    @Transactional
    private void printed() {
        inst = entityManager.find(Invoice.class, inst.getId());
        inst.setPrinted(true);
            // on the line below exception is thrown
        entityManager.merge(inst);
        entityManager.flush();
    }

}
```

In this case on sendEmail("invoice") execution application fails on instance merging in printed() method with exception:

```
11:20:36,199 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)

11:20:36,199 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:855)

11:20:36,200 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.merge(AbstractEntityManager.java:553)

11:20:36,200 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:20:36,200 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

11:20:36,200 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:20:36,200 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

11:20:36,200 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:412)

11:20:36,201 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.CallableMethodHandler.invoke(CallableMethodHandler.java:42)

11:20:36,201 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)

11:20:36,201 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)

11:20:36,201 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weldx.persistence.EntityManager$863717792$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.merge(Unknown Source)

11:20:36,201 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.i4u.qla.action.invoice.InvMailForm.printed(InvMailForm.java:78)

11:20:36,201 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.i4u.qla.action.invoice.InvMailForm.sendInvoice(InvMailForm.java:54)

11:20:36,202 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.i4u.qla.action.invoice.InvMailForm.sendMail(InvMailForm.java:42)

11:20:36,202 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.i4u.qla.action.invoice.InvMailForm$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.sendMail(Unknown Source)

11:20:36,202 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:20:36,202 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

11:20:36,202 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:20:36,202 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

11:20:36,203 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.interceptorChainCompleted(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:51)

11:20:36,203 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:96)

11:20:36,203 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:43)

11:20:36,203 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:36)

11:20:36,203 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:51)

11:20:36,203 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.i4u.qla.action.invoice.InvMailForm$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.sendMail(Unknown Source)

11:20:36,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.i4u.qla.action.invoice.InvMailForm$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.sendMail(Unknown Source)

11:20:36,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:20:36,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

11:20:36,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:20:36,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

11:20:36,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)

11:20:36,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)

11:20:36,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)

11:20:36,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)

11:20:36,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)

11:20:36,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)

11:20:36,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)

11:20:36,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)

11:20:36,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)

11:20:36,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)

11:20:36,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)

11:20:36,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)

11:20:36,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)

11:20:36,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)

11:20:36,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)

11:20:36,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)

11:20:36,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

11:20:36,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

11:20:36,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)

11:20:36,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

11:20:36,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)

11:20:36,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)

11:20:36,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)

11:20:36,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)

11:20:36,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.i4u.app.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:37)

11:20:36,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)

11:20:36,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)

11:20:36,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)

11:20:36,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)

11:20:36,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

11:20:36,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

11:20:36,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

11:20:36,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)

11:20:36,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52)

11:20:36,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)

11:20:36,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)

11:20:36,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)

11:20:36,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)

11:20:36,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

11:20:36,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

11:20:36,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

11:20:36,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)

11:20:36,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)

11:20:36,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)

11:20:36,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)

11:20:36,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)

11:20:36,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168)

11:20:36,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687)

11:20:36,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

11:20:36,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

11:20:36,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

In other places similar codes works fine.

**What cases can avoid @Transactional interceptor (or any interceptor) fireing?**

I will be glad for any clue to find root cause. 
Now, after several days I'm sitting, crying and I really have no idea which way to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the public accesible method (`sendMail()`) as @Transactional.

The `@Transactional` anotation is supported by a CDI interceptor, and thus, only methods called by "client" classes are intercepted (this is, mostly public or protected methods, and called from another class).

So, if the `sendMail` is not invoked in a transactional context, the `merge` operation called at merge fails.

More info on CDI Interceptors:

- http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/interceptors.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhjx.html

Comment: Thank you, it really helped. But I'm more confused now. Could you look into [link](http://pastebin.com/G0tCRd9Q) ? I have there public accessible method remove(CntContract inst) method with @Transactional annotation - this method also throws TransactionRequiredException :-(

Comment: Depending on the method that fires the remove operation. I see that your parent class has a not-anotated `remove()` method. The call between members of the same class won't be intercepted.

Comment: Yes, right, but I'm fireing remove(CntContract inst) method (by jsf button - el expression) in child class and Exception I have thrown. Sorry for remove() method - it shouldn't be taken into account. Can you see any mistake there?

Comment: At a First glance, I don't see anything else. Have you tried adding the anotation at the parent method declaration?

Comment: Yes I've tried. I'm starting to give up. Maybe I should try with manual #UserTransaction.begin()/commit().

Comment: Ok Tomas, after different tries - I see that is cases when @Transactional not working for me I have to fire the method of injected object from other class - as you mentioned in your main answer - so thank you very much. I marked question as solved.