# How to make database update when method finish in JPA

Tags: hibernate, rest, jpa, jta

There is a business logic where one method is called first which save the entity. next method fetches some the data from DB. when second method called that result list contains previous value of entity because entity is not saved yet. Is there any way to synch this business logic so that second method called after first method transaction get finished.

Used EntityManager em to persist the data, here the code

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class DemoService { 

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager em;

    public  Demo createOrUpdate (Demo obj) {

      //This function is to update enity
      createOrUpdate_(obj);

      //In this function need to get updated enities(latest saved)
      fetchResultSet();
      return obj;  
    }


    @Transactional
    public  Demo createOrUpdate_ (Demo obj) {
      em.merge(obj);
      return obj;  
    }

}
```

Comment: As you call a method from the same class your @Transactional on createOrUpdate won't do anything. So two possible solutions: Move createOrUpdate to another service or get a reference to demoService and call the public method so the Transaction Interceptor will do it's job.

Comment: Thanks for response but is there any reason for this "As you call a method from the same class your @Transactional on createOrUpdate won't do anything."?

Comment: Well for a bean with @Transactional annotation an proxy-object is created. If you inject this bean anywhere and use it, you're acessing the bean through the proxy. The proxy takes care of the transaction handling. But if you directly call your method from inside your class you don't go through this proxy. So no transaction will be created. Maybe the links in the answer of this thread can also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194777/jee7-transactional-annotation-not-always-fires

Comment: Okay and when i called my second method from out side(from rest service) it dosed work. what i have notice is DML query gets executed in the last when first method returns response to rest service.even if remove @Transactional it behaves same.@TomStoemer

Comment: As your entire bean is an EJB and annotated with @TransactionalAttribute, all methods are also transactional except if annotated otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When you call your fetchResultSet() method, the commit did not occur - it happens when the calling method, in your case, createOrUpdate(Demo obj), ends without any exceptions.

You also are returning not the merged entity on your createOrUpdate_(Demo) method. Please note that, per API, EntityManager#merge(T) has as return object them managed entity, so your pointer obj may be linked to your original entity. On a side note, you, ideally, should not use entityManager directly in your service classes.

I suggest that you change your code to something like this (not complete, using EJB and not CDI, but I think it shows enough). First, a base manager.

```
public abstract BaseManager<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    protected abstract Class<T> getEntityClass();

    @TransactionAttribute
    public T createOrUpdate(T e) {
        if (em.contains(e)) {
            em.persist(e);
            return e;
        } else {
            return em.merge(e);
        }
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        String q = String.format("SELECT o FROM %s AS o", getEntityClass().toCanonicalName()0;
        return em.createQuery(q, getEntityClass()).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Then, the entity manager:

```
@Stateless
public DemoManager extends BaseManager<Demo> {

    protected Class<Demo> getEntityClass() {
        return Demo.class;
    }
}
```

Now, your service class:

```
@Stateless
public ExampleService {

    @EJB
    private DemoManager demoManager;

    public Set<Demo> addDemoToSet(Demo demo) {
        demoManager.createOrUpdate(demo);
        return new HashSet<>(demoManager.findAll());
    }
}
```

With this approach, the call to demoManager.createOrUpdate will be transactional and your findAll subsequent call will get all itens (if this is your goal).